# Maven build fails after upgrading to maven-source-plugin from 3.2.1 to 3.3.0

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I recently upgraded the maven-source-plugin version in my project from 3.2.1 to 3.3.0 and now I am encountering the following error during the build process:

> Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-source-plugin:3.3.0:jar (attach-sources) on project xxx: Presumably you have configured maven-source-plugn to execute twice times in your build. You have to configure a classifier for at least on of them. -> [Help 1]

It seems that this error is related to the fact that the maven-source-plugin has changed its behavior in version 3.3.0 to prevent the attach-sources goal from being executed multiple times during the build. However, I can't find any doc or release note related to this feature that may cause this incompatibility problem.

I want to know where I can find the official documentation and what the purpose of this new feature is? Thanks~

Comment: That is an hint that you have a wrong configuration in your build... either inherited through parent or alike... Please check the log output ...because I suppose it will be executed at least two times... etc.  Reference: https://lists.apache.org/thread/clgkh4809octgrv3o0p9fm1nzfvs6l2p Link to the appropriate issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MSOURCES-121

Comment: I found exactly the same error: https://github.com/JEsperancinhaOrg/consolerizer-root/actions/runs/5050076108/jobs/9060326828?pr=53. I have no idea even where to start.

Comment: I had the same error happening to me. Turns out I had specified both the `jar` and the `jar-no-fork` goals...

Comment: I'm also encountering this issue which is a result of https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MSOURCES-121. Unfortuanately I don't have enough information to understand if that's a bug in my pom or in the plugin.

Comment: Had same error, was due to `shade` plugin with `createSourcesJar` running before source plugin. Fixed by moving `maven-source-plugin:jar` to `package` phase ([Usage](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/usage.html) docs has it set to `verify`.)

Answer (score 7):

Since `3.3.0` the duplicate check will also fails build when multiple lifecycle phase which are bound to the `jar-no-fork` goal of the sources plugin are given on the command line. For example

```
# mvn package install
# mvn install deploy
```

The solution is to simply avoid the unnecessary lifecycle phase:

```
# mvn install
# mvn deploy
```

However, upgrading to `maven-sources-plugin` **3.3.0** will break quite a number of build I presume.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue after upgrading from `3.2.1` to `3.3.0`.

The error was resolved after changing the `goal` from `jar` to `jar-no-fork`:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>attach-sources</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score -3):

If you're encountering difficulties with your pom configuration and need a workaround, you can skip the maven-source-plugin (this will prevent 'artifact-sources.jar' deployment) by utilizing the **'-Dmaven.source.skip'** parameter in your mvn command.

mvn help:describe -Dplugin=org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-source-plugin

> Available parameters:
>
> skipSource (Default: false)
>
> User property: maven.source.skip
> A flag used to disable the source procedure. 
> This is primarily intended
> for usage from the command line to occasionally adjust the build.

For versions of the 'maven-source-plugin' up to 2.4, you should use '-Dsource.skip'.
For version 3.0.0 and later, employ '-Dmaven.source.skip' instead.

Comment: This is not a solution, there is a good reason to want sources deployed and simply skipping the sources is not acceptable in many if not most cases.

Answer (score -4):

I had the same problem yesterday and I solved adding this in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>3.2.1</version>
</dependency>

<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>3.2.1</version>             
</plugin>
```

Comment: This post is not helpful. He asks regarding the problem when upgrading from 3.2.1 to 3.3.0.